# Display error with <li> elements on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-lists

I am trying to create a list for a website I am working on but I noticed after checking in firefox the list elements were not displaying consistently. I checked IE, opera and safari and they all displayed them correctly. I attached the image (below) of what it looks like on firefox vs. chrome. I am using a separate reset style sheet (Eric Meyer version) that resets basically everything including li elements.

[image]

Here is the css code:

```
ol{
list-style-type:decimal;
list-style-position:inside;
}

li{
padding:2px;
font-size:18px;
text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: 1. the issue definitely not related to `ol` only, but to its containter 2. where is html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try setting  `line-height:18px;`

Comment: than there must me something wrong with your `li height` try setting it and than delete `padding:2px`. or leave just `padding:0 2px`

Comment: Thanks, this work perfectly. I have been looking everywhere to find out what the problem was. I feel like an idiot for not trying height. Again thanks a million.